# Polymer paper-dropdown-menu getting selected item

Tags: polymer

I'm having problems understanding how to get the index (or the item) of the selected item in paper-dropdown-menu. At the moment I have an eventlistener whenever core-select is fired:

```
window.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(e) {
  var menu = document.querySelector('paper-dropdown');
  menu.addEventListener('core-select', function(e) {
    console.log(getSelection());
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs (https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/paper-elements.html#paper-dropdown-menu), the event has and `.item` property with the selected item.

```
menu.addEventListener('core-select', function(e) {
  console.log(e.detail.item);
});
```

Comment: I believe this is along the lines of what I'm trying to do. See my issue: [How to extend paper-dropdown-menu for a reusable custom element list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512699/how-to-extend-paper-dropdown-menu-for-a-reusable-custom-element-list). If you have an answer, please help.